# How to fix errors that showing when I'm using command npm run build?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I try to run `npm run build` output is below error:

```
   root@tim-VPCEB42EG:/home/tavinder/es6# npm run build
    npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
    npm ERR! node v4.2.6
    npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2

    npm ERR! missing script: build
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/tavinder/es6/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: could you put your `package.json` file here?

Comment: What's the version of node you're using?

Comment: Please include your package.json

Answer (score 0):

It means you're missing a script.NPM should know which script to run when that command is executed. If you have a build script, in your package.json, under scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
    "build": "name of your build script"
  },
```

For example, on one of my projects,

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint . --fix || true",
    "build": "babel src -d dist --presets es2015",
     .....
  }
```

Comment: Yep !! I got it but build is already settled to "build" = "webpack" I don't know what else i need to put there ?

Comment: I have some issue with webpack. Just check this out -

Comment: webpack -v
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:89
 let notify =
 ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3

Comment: @MIKEYSINGH I may sound stupid, but just checking. Have you installed webpack?

Comment: Yeah, i did lol but it ended up successfully with some errors like some dependencies aren't supported in your operating system. Actually, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Btw I'm using node v4.2.6 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your node version: 4.2.6
Node version required by latest version of webpack : minimum 6.11.6
You either need to update your node or use a version of webpack that's compatible with our node version
[image]